# Replace string with HTML equivalent. Apart from <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, code-injection

How could I go about replacing a `string`:

```
Hello my name is <a href='/max'>max</a>! 
<script>alert("DANGEROUS SCRIPT INJECTION");</script>
```

with

```
Hello my name is <a href='/max'>max</a>! 
&lt;script&gt;alert("DANGEROUS SCRIPT INJECTION");&lt;/script&gt;
```

---

I can easily have all the `<`,`>` replaced with `&lt;`,`&gt;` with:

```
string = string.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

but I still want to be able to have `<a>` links.

---

I have also looked into preventing script injection with:

```
var html = $(string.bold()); 
html.find('script').remove();
```

But I want to be able to still read the script tags rather than them being removed.

Comment: You would be better to not allow any HTML in the string and have a predefined format for inserting links, similar to how SO does it (eg. `[linktext](http://linkurl.com)`). This way you have no HTML in the string and have complete control over what gets added.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that's not a duplicate - it removes *all* HTML from a string. The OP is looking to retain `a` elements (and presumably others too)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah, I see. I missed reading that.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Why have you marked this as a duplicate? I have acknowledged a similar answer to the one you marked. I am asking for help on top of that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan to expand a little more. A user will enter a message like "check out this link so.com" and I want to transfer that to `check out this link <a href="so.com">so.com</a>` I have already done that using regex but now the user can also write "check out this link so.com <script>...</script>"

Comment: So you think the regex should change it to `check out this link [so.com](http://so.com)` and replace all the HTML tags. Then another function to turn `[so.com](http://so.com)` into `<a href="so.com">so.com</a>` to run straight after?

Comment: based on that last comment, you should still sanitise the input first, then generate the link

Comment: If that's the functionality you should store the data in plain text (stripping out all HTML) and then add the links using Regex only when it is displayed on the client.

Comment: This method could then have users typing "`check out this link [so.com](http://dangerous.com)`" ?

Comment: You could use `var newStr = $('<div>', {html: str}).find(':not(a)').replaceWith(function(){
  return this.outerHTML.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
}).end().html();` where `str` is your original string. That's said, you have certainly better to do...

Comment: @A.Wolff why have you not written that as an answer?

Comment: @Maximilian Because i think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and i'm sure you have better to do. If i understand it, you are trying to sanitize data client side following any user input. But an user could still send whatever he wants. So if you have to sanitize some data, it has to be done server side, not client side

Comment: The solution by @A.Wolff is incomplete, it will allow things like `<a href="javascript:alert('evil');">` anchors and many more problematic things such as event handler attributes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this problem is to use a regular expression with a strict look-behind pattern that only allows anchors that follow a certain format very closely.

Let's say you want to only allow links that exactly follow this example:

```
<a href="http://host.domain/path?query#anchor">text</a>
```

and

```
<a href="https://host.domain/path?query#anchor">text</a>
```

Build a regular expression that matches only "<" characters that are not followed by this valid pattern (negative lookbehind):

```
<(?!a href="https?:\/\/\w[\w.-\/\?#]+">\w+<\/a>)
```

One problem with this regular expression is that if you match it against your entire string, the `<` will still match the closing `a` element (`</a>`), so if you replace every match with a `&lt;` you will break the anchor after all.

You can allow all closing `</a>` tags by appending an alternative to the negative look-behind:

```
<(?!a href="https?:\/\/\w[\w.-\/\?#]+">\w+<\/a>|\/a>)
```

Perhaps someone else has a better solution for that sub-problem.

Here is the final string.replace:

```
string.replace(/<(?!a href="https?:\/\/\w[\w.-\/\?#]+">\w+<\/a>|\/a>)/g, '&lt;');
```

Note: All these input checks **must always be done on the server side**, on the client side the check can simply be circumvented and you'll have malicious data sent to your server despite the check.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should do the trick. You can add additional tag names you wish to let pass as HTML tags in the array `allowedTagNames`.

```
// input
var html = "Hello my name is <a href='/max'>max</a>! <script>alert('DANGEROUS SCRIPT INJECTION');</script>";

var allowedTagNames = ["a"];
// output
var processedHTML = "";

var processingStart = 0;
// this block finds the next tag and processes it
while (true) {
    var tagStart = html.indexOf("<", processingStart);
    if (tagStart === -1) { break; }

    var tagEnd = html.indexOf(">", tagStart);
    if (tagEnd === -1) { break; }

    var tagNameStart = tagStart + 1;
    if (html[tagNameStart] === "/") {
        // for closing tags
        ++tagNameStart;
    }
    // we expect there to be either a whitespace or a > after the tagName
    var tagNameEnd = html.indexOf(" ", tagNameStart);
    if (tagNameEnd === -1 || tagNameEnd > tagEnd) {
        tagNameEnd = tagEnd;
    }

    var tagName = html.slice(tagNameStart, tagNameEnd);
    // copy in text which is between this tag and the end of last tag
    processedHTML += html.slice(processingStart, tagStart);
    if (allowedTagNames.indexOf(tagName) === -1) {
        processedHTML += "&lt;" + html.slice(tagStart + 1, tagEnd) + "&gt;";
    } else {
        processedHTML += html.slice(tagStart, tagEnd + 1);
    }
    processingStart = tagEnd + 1;
}
// copy the rest of input which wasn't processed
processedHTML += html.slice(processingStart);
```

**NOTE:** it won't work if there's a `<` or `>` inside a property of a tag.
For example: `<a href=">">`

Comment: This will not prevent malicious <a> tags. Consider javascript: links, event handler attributes etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture groups and lookarounds in Regex to achieve this

```
string = string.replace(/<((?!a )[^>]*)>/g, "&lt;$1&gt;").replace(/&lt;\/a&gt;/g, "</a>");
```

The first part replaces all the HTML tags (except anchor start tags <a>) from `<tag>` to `&lt;tag&gt;` and the second part replaces all the altered anchor end tags(</a>) from `&lt;/a&gt;` back to `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only the `<script...` tags, the following code will do the trick ( you can run it in browser console ) and all other tags will not be changed. In my sample I added an extra line just to demonstrate how it works with multiple `<script...` tags inside.

```js
let s = "Hello my name is <a href='/max'>max</a>!<script>alert(\"DANGEROUS SCRIPT INJECTION\");</script>";
s += "Hello my name is <a href='/bob'>bob</a>!<script>alert(\"DANGEROUS SCRIPT INJECTION\");</script>";

s.match(/<script.*?<\/script>/g).forEach(scr => s = s.replace(scr, scr.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")));

console.log(s);
// OUTPUT: Hello my name is <a href='/max'>max</a>!&lt;script&gt;alert("DANGEROUS SCRIPT INJECTION");&lt;/script&gt;Hello my name is <a href='/bob'>bob</a>!&lt;script&gt;alert("DANGEROUS SCRIPT INJECTION");&lt;/script&gt;
```